# How to connect two computers with same Private IP addresses but on different LAN

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, lan, nat

There are two devices in different cities and both of these have same private IP addresses. How do I get them communicated (SSH, RDP, FTP, Telnet, etc). Please explain in detail.

Thank you

Comment: The private IP doesn't matter, since communication is done via the Internet, where the two routers have different IP addresses. You don't care about the internal IPs, but you will need to port-forward in each router the right ports to your computer. The subject is to vast to cover here.

Comment: One big question is - are these two locations part of the same company network or peering between companies that are connected together through some type of WAN technology like a site-to-site VPN? If they are just completely unrelated networks then this happens ALL the time and the simple answer is port forwarding. If they are part of the same homogenous network then the answer is most likely static NAT where you convert an internal network address to a different network address to traverse the WAN and eliminate the conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are talking about two standard residential or commercial internet connections (and not a leased line or two sites linked by VPN or similar).

With the example network below, we have two buildings and a server (anywhere in the world) that are connected via the internet. We have two routers - `R1` and `R2` - each of which have a different ***public*** IP address (or "*external*" IP address).

Within the buildings, the routers and devices all share common IP addresses - the routers (`R1` and `R2`) use a ***private*** IP of `192.168.0.1`, and the devices (`DA` and `DB`) use a ***private*** IP of `192.168.0.10`.

Externally to the buildings, the routers have different ***public*** IP addresses - `203.0.113.5` and `203.0.113.219`. The server is accessible on the ***public*** IP address `203.0.113.42`.

[image: example network]

---

There is an important distinction between two types of IP address here, more information can be found on the wiki page, "[*Reserved IP addresses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)".

- Public Network - these are accessible directly on the internet

  - Note: I've actually used a set of network addresses that are reserved for documentation instead of real public addresses here
- Private Network - these are only intended for use within a network

For `DA` to access a server or host on the internet (for example, `203.0.113.42`), it needs to get help from a router - because `203.0.113.42` is not accessible on the local network. So it will send the packets to the configured router (`R1`), which will then forward the packets on to the internet.

In this case, the router will rewrite the packet slightly, marking the "*Source Address*" as `R1`'s public address (`203.0.113.5`), instead of `DA`'s address (`192.168.0.10`). When a packet is then returned to `R1`, it will check the connection tables, rewrite the packet so that the destination is `DA` again, and forward the packet on to the local network.

This is called [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT), and the rewriting of the outgoing packets to use the router's own address is called "*Masquerading*" - i.e: all outbound packets appear to have originated from the router, not a device behind it.

This allows for communication between devices on a private network (e.g: `DA` and `DB`) and a public server on the internet.

---

To present some services provided inside Building A's network, we need to make `R1` look more like the Server at `203.0.113.42`... To do this we introduce [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

This is a technique that allows us to configure `R1` to accept incoming connection requests on a port (for example `22` for [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)), and forward them to another host within the private network it's servicing.

In this case, `DA` has an SSH server running on port `22`, so we configure `R1` to forward port 22 on its external interface (i.e: `203.0.113.5:22`) to the server on its internal interface (i.e: `192.168.0.10:22`).

Now that we've configured the port forwarding, `DB` can access `DA`'s SSH server by connecting to `R1`'s public address... which is `203.0.113.5`, port `22`. **Note:** `DB` does not use or ever need to know `DA`'s private IP address, and vice-versa.

The network address translation will be taken care of for you, and the full chain will look something like this:

- `DB` sends a packet to `R2` - Source: `192.168.0.10`, Destination: `203.0.113.5`
- `R2` rewrites the packet - Source: `203.0.113.219`, Destination: `203.0.113.5`

  - `R2` sends the packet over the internet, and `R1` receives it
- `R1` rewrites the packet - Source: `203.0.113.219`, Destination: `192.168.0.10`

  - `R1` sends the packet over the local network, and `DA` receives it

The return path / response is the inverse:

- `DA` sends a packet to `R1` - Source: `192.168.0.10`, Destination: `203.0.113.219`
- `R1` rewrites the packet - Source `203.0.113.5`, Destination: `203.0.113.219`

  - `R1` sends the packet over the internet, and `R2` receives it
- `R2` rewrites the packet - Source: `203.0.113.5`, Destination: `192.168.0.10`

  - `R2` sends the packet over the local network, and `DB` receives it

As you can see, the colliding private addresses doesn't matter at all - no single device is ever in a situation where `192.168.0.10` is seen as both source and destination, or could be reached over two interfaces. If this were true, then the link would clearly not work.

---

Some notes:

- The configuration interface for routers varies significantly, so walking you through the port forwarding setup isn't something we can do without knowing what router you have.
- Setting up port forwarding like this will make your service accessible to the whole internet (unless you also configure firewall rules).
- I would strongly advise against setting up unencrypted services (e.g: Telnet / FTP) in this way. Prefer SSH / SFTP.
- You **must** ensure that your services are suitably protected - e.g: authentication, rate limiting, etc...